# Как закодировать большой массив байтов в base64 без Out of memory в Java?

Tags: java, base64, bytearray

На вход приходит **byte[] fileData**, надо получить на выходе закодированный String

`String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileData)` выбрасывает  Out of memory.

Можно ли как-то закодировтаь по частям и потом собрать все это в String?

Comment: а сколько памяти выделено для JVM и сколько используется для этой операции?

Comment: Массив может быть любого размера, памяти можно много выделить, но ее всегда может не хватить, в этом и проблема. -Xmx2096M

Comment: Кодируйте блоками, длина которых кратна трем байтам. И отдавайте закодированный результат сразу на выход что бы память не занимал

Comment: Если вы читаете из файла и пишете в файл, то да, читайте блоками, пишите блоками. Если же вам надо строку составить в памяти, то вы не сможете в памяти составить строку прямо любого размера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо кодировать кусками, просто при этом надо держать в голове, что по сути алгоритм base64 - это превращение 3 байт - в 4 байта, то есть если длина исходного бинарного массива кратна 3, то никаких проблем не возникает, проблема возникает только если длина массива некратна 3 - тогда начинается всякая муть связанная с выравниванием - в стандарте символ выравнивания это `=` (хотя можно и другой). Например:

> abc - YWJj
>
> ab - YWI=
>
> a - YQ==

соответственно при кодировании кусками надо учитывать эту особенность base64:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 3 * 1024;

try ( BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input, BUFFER_SIZE); ) {
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] chunk = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int len = 0;
    while ( (len = in.read(chunk)) == BUFFER_SIZE ) {
         result.append( encoder.encodeToString(chunk) );
    }
    if ( len > 0 ) {
         chunk = Arrays.copyOf(chunk,len);
         result.append( encoder.encodeToString(chunk) );
    }
}
```